# nmcli slower than netsh stablishing connection

Tags: linux, windows, networking, netsh

I want a crossplatform (linux and windows) solution for **searching networks** and connecting to them. In linux I use `nmcli` giving the **SSID** and the **password**. In windows I use `netsh` giving a **profile** `xml` wiht network information.

The thing is that in windows, netsh is absolutely faster than in linux nmcli. Why am I having this behaviour? Is it because I am using proifiles for netsh?

Comment: How much time difference are we talking about? Is there anything visible in the NetworkManager logs (perhaps after increasing the log level)?

Comment: In linux 10 seconds to connect to WiFi, and in windows less than 2 seconds. I'd need to have a look to the logs.

Comment: No, the Windows regularly polls the list of the available networks, and the netsh gives you this list. The Linux nmcli does a polling as the part of the command execution. The result is that the Linux nmcli is slower, but much more exact.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming, but about Linux usage. I suggest to re-ask this question on https://unix.stackexchange.com .